# How to fit proportionally Cardviews inside of a NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-cardview

What I'm trying to do is create a "table" 2 Rows and 1 Column using cardview, so far I have this :

[image]

But I want that way!

[image]

The purple color belongs to a `RelativeLayout` and the black, to a NestedScrollView, I need to make those Cards stretch along the layout, and not leaving any gap at the bottom, it has to be the same way as the top.
My code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_painel"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.org.barros.test.Painel"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_painel">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:emojicon="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:visibility="visible">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#4CAF50">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="56dp"
                    android:paddingTop="56dp"
                    emojicon:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#4CAF50">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="56dp"
                    android:paddingTop="56dp"

                    emojicon:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"

                app:cardBackgroundColor="#009688">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="56dp"
                    android:paddingTop="56dp"

                    emojicon:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#2196F3">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="56dp"
                    android:paddingTop="56dp"

                    emojicon:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#009688">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="56dp"
                    android:paddingTop="56dp"

                    emojicon:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#2196F3">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="56dp"
                    android:paddingTop="56dp"

                    emojicon:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Why not use Grid View for that purpose ??

Comment: if you could help me, I would be grateful

Comment: Have you tried android:layout_height="wrap_content" instead of android:layout_height="match_parent" in NestedScrollView?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you facing? Just want to remove the white spaces??

Comment: Yeah, I want to remove the white space at the bottom of it, that fit the same way as the top. Something [THIS](http://oi66.tinypic.com/29mnok9.jpg), the top and bottom are the same padding

Comment: I still can't get it what you want, clear yourself a little bit, and explain

Comment: I update with a background color so you could see what I'm trying to say.